# Making 1.0 Contour

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, contour

I am making a plot and overlaying contours over it. I am using the code

```
thetap = np.linspace(0, 91, 1000)
r = np.linspace(1, 13, 1000, endpoint = True)
mesht, meshr = np.meshgrid(thetap, r)
meshtheta = mesht * (np.pi / 180)
numerator = 1 - meshr * (np.tan(meshtheta)) ** 2
denominator = (1 + meshr) * np.tan(meshtheta)

wk = np.cos(np.arctan(numerator / denominator))

ar = np.arange(0, 1.01, 0.2)
contour = plt.contour(meshr, mesht, wk, levels = ar, colors = "k", linewidths = 0.75)
```

which produces this plot

[image]

My issue is that matplotlib will not draw the wk = 1 contour, which will be at theta prime = 45. I believe the issue is that the wk equation has a max value of wk = 1. Based on the thetap and r matrices there are not enough points where wk = 1 for matplotlib to draw a contour line. I have tried to increase the size of the thetap and r matrices to no avail. Is there any way to get matplotlib to draw the wk = 1 contour or will I have to manually create it in Illustrator?

Comment: You could try to add an epsilon to `wk` to make it slightly larger than `1`. E.g. `
wk = np.cos(np.arctan(numerator / denominator)) + 0.000001`.  (Also note that your denominator is zero when the angle is zero, leading to a divide-by-zero error.)

Comment: Adding an epsilon worked great! Thanks for the help!